# Prove that the spectral radius $\rho(A)$ is a continuous function, where $A$ is a square matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $||. ||$ be some norm on $\mathbb{R^n}.$ Interpret the real-valued matrices as a Euclidean space, $\mathbb{R^{n^2}}=Mat_{n\times n},$ and prove that the following are continuous functions of the $n^2$ matrix entries $A_{ij}$

(a) The spectral radius of $A$, $\rho(A)=\max\{|\lambda| ~~| \text{such that}~\lambda 
~\text{is an eigenvalue of}~A  \}.$

(b) The spectral radius of the inverse, $f(A)=\rho (A^{-1}),$ on the domain of invertible matrices.

---

For part (b), I think the goal is $\displaystyle\lim_{\Delta A \to 0} \rho(A+\Delta A)=\rho(A).$
I tried to use Gelfand formula. Then I have $\rho(A)=\displaystyle\lim_{\Delta A \to 0} \rho(A+\Delta A)=\displaystyle\lim_{\Delta A \to 0} \lim_{k\to \infty}||(A+\Delta A)^k||^{1/k},$ which becomes more complicated. In addition, I tried to use the operator norm to bound the spectral radius, but I felt that I was still far away from the proof.

Why does the part (b) need to prove if the part (a) is true? $f(A)=\rho(A) $ restrict on the domain of invertable matrices. I was confuled about part(b).

---

I know how to prove this statement using a theorem in complex analysis: The roots of a complex-valued polynomial are continuous wrt the coefficients of the polynomial.

By using this theorem, (b) is very easy to prove.

I am looking for another proof of (b) without the theorem in complex analysis.

Comment: (b) follows from (a) because $A\mapsto A^{-1}$ is continuous on $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ regardless of norm (all of them are equivalent anyway).

Comment: @freakish Thanks. But how to prove part(b)?

Comment: Does anyone know whether the functions $f_k:M_{n\times n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,  $f_k(A) = \|A^k\|^{\frac{1}{k}}$, have derivatives $\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial a_{ij}}$ uniformly bounded (in $k$) when $f_k$'s are restricted to some compact set of matrices? Then one could use limit theorems to show spectral radius is continuous.

Comment: (specifically the arzela-ascoli theorem)

Comment: I think you can find a solution in this forum. I remember seeing a proof using complex analysis. It seems that Rouche theorem applies.

Comment: @i707107 Yes. I can prove it using complex analysis. But I am looking for a proof without complex analysis.

Comment: What is the spectral radius when $A$ does not have eigenvalues; for example, where the field is $\mathbb{R}$.